# What prettier extension settings to use to format my react code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using VS code editor, I've installed prettier but my code still sticks together instead of moving on to the next line. I tried changing a few settings but didn't work very well. Here's a sample code

```js
return (<>
        <span style={{display:"flex",color:"white"}}>
            <img src={comment.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorProfileImageUrl}  onError={(e)=>{e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRlsUYbM6jWxjKND6TCCeEE5sBTwEJqyUhtLg&usqp=CAU"}} alt="" style={{borderRadius:"50%",width:30,height:30,border:"None"}}></img>
    <span><h6>{comment.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName}</h6>{comment.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal}</span>
        </span>
        <div>{comment.replies!==undefined?<><button className="comment"  onClick={toggle} style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' ,marginLeft:'2rem'}}>replies</button>
        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
          <div>
            <div>
            <Replies replies={comment.replies}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Collapse></>:null}
        
      </div></>
    )
```

Comment: Have you installed the "Prettier - Code formatter" extension for VS Code?

Comment: yes ,of course .

Comment: And you've installed the "prettier" npm package?

Comment: isn't the extension sufficient?no i haven't

Comment: Give that a shot; I believe you can either install it globally or on a per-project basis. I also find it helpful to enable "editor.formatOnSave" in VS Code's settings.json.

Comment: installed it but still not working..the  formatOnSave is already enabled

Comment: Oh it worked : ) when i clicked ctrl +s ...but its strange as i remember changing the settings to autosave..so i think it should save automatically..anyways thank you : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218477/discussion-between-william-lewis-and-cosmiccallisto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prettier latest version [3.17.0]
vs code latest version 1.41.1
Format on Save is 'ON'
Default Formatter esbenp.prettier-vscode